# Add a onChanged callback to a SwiftUI struct for emitting values

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to emmit values from a SwiftUI component. I wan't to have an API like `DragGesture` (as an example).

```swift
DragGesture()
  .onChanged { value in
     print("Get access to value when it changes \(value)")
  }
```

How can I add a callback function like that to `MyCustomComponent`? I would prefer to have the exact same syntax. The component will emit values continously (based on a DragGesture locally inside the component. [Code for the Component I wan't to augment can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/eivindml/28e81d630cdd59521240a9adada7ddc2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found this answer by @Asperi, which shows how to do it like I wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780177/swiftui-how-add-custom-modifier-with-callback?rq=1). The trick is to actually return a copy of itself.

```
typealias OnChange = ((CGFloat) -> Void)?

struct WheelView: View {
  var action: OnChange

  func onChanged(perform action: OnChange) -> Self {
    var copy = self
    copy.action = action
    return copy
  }

  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
          //  Emit the angle change
          if let action = self.action {
            action(0.4)
          }
      })
  }
}
```

Then we can use our component like this:

```
struct Usage: View {
  var body: some View {
    WheelView()
      .onChanged { value in
        print("Value is \(value)")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i really like your wheelbutton and learnt a lot from it...but why did you define position as CGSize and not as CGPoint? (this irritated me ;) )

Comment: Hehe. Just didn't think about it I guess. It should be a CGPoint.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of possible approaches (simplest IMO) ...

```
struct WheelView: View {
    var onEmit: (CGFloat) -> Void

    init(onEmit: @escaping (CGFloat)-> Void = {_ in }) {
        self.onEmit = onEmit
    }

    ...

    // TODO: Emit angle from here
    self.onEmit(self.angle)
}
```

usage (in any place of `ViewBuilder`)

```
WheelView() { angle in
    print("\(angle)")
}
```

Comment: Ok, so there is now way to do it with syntax similar to `DragGesture`? Do Apple have access to some other functionality to create structs with API's like that?

I'm curious to how to achieve that, and I find the syntax more readable/discoverable, and if I for instances wan't to add more, like a `onCompleted` callback etc., to other API seems better.

Comment: See for example `TextField` constructors with `onEditingChanged` and `onCommit`... also you can create custom modifiers. But as was noted provided variant is simplest.